Postfix/Dovecot log: "auth: Warning: auth client 0 disconnected with 1 pending requests: EOF" - how to hide/fix
I've got a Debian mail server and set up error logging mails. I always used to get a lot of emails with the following line:
auth: Warning: auth client 0 disconnected with 1 pending requests: EOF
Maybe a couple or so a day. But lately, I've been getting like 10+ per hour, so it's really annoying spam.
From reading previous threads related to this the responses indicate there's no reason to be concerned about this... however, I just want to "turn it off" so I get my log email folder free for actual important errors and not this particular Postfix error.
So my question is, how can I turn this particular error off? (Or fix it, if there's a fix...)
